# Diferença entre funções de scroll?

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma diferença em usar:

```
$(window).scrollTop(_Altura_);
```

Ou

```
window.scroll(0,_Altura_);
```

Sem ser o controle da posição do eixo horizontal? 
(considere `_Altura_` como uma variável)

Comment: Uma é função do jQuery e outra é JS *vanilla*. Que tipo de comparação você deseja fazer? Apenas em questões de resultados ou também de performance?

Comment: Resultados e performance, Porém acho que o resultado será o mesmo não ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas geram o mesmo resultado a diferença é que a função `jQuery` [.scrollTop](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.scrollTop) usa o `window.scrollTo` para executar que é o mesmo que [Window.scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll).

Portanto conseguirmos concluir que o `window.scroll` terá uma performance mais rápida por ser `JS` puro.

> window.scroll -> window.scrollTo is effectively the same as this method.

Outro ponto é que a função do `jQuery`, `.scrollTop()`, funciona com qualquer elemento do [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM) e também pode trabalhar como getter quando não for passado nenhum parâmetro, já a do `vanilla`, `scroll`, não possui retorno e é aplicada ao objeto [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window).

```js
$(() => {
  $("#window").on("click", event => {
    $(window).scrollTop(100);
  });
  
  $("#div").on("click", event => {
    $("div.demo").scrollTop(300);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

div.demo {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.demo p {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="window">Scroll na window</button>
<button id="div">Scroll no elemento</button>
<div class="demo">
  <p>Stack Overflow em Português</p>
  <span>Estou a 300px do topo.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Talvez valha a pena comentar que a função do jQuery, `scrollTop`, funciona também como *getter* quando não passado nenhum parâmetro, já a do *vanilla*, `scroll`, não possui retorno.

Comment: Acrescentei na resposta